# extract inner classes using eclipse JDT

Tags: eclipse-jdt

i want to parse a project in which some classes have inner classes.how can i extract inner classes name other information using eclips JDT?

Comment: How is this related to javascript ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can traverse through the `Compilation` unit of the Java class and visit the `TypeDeclaration` AST node. The below code can then be used to check if it is not a top-level class, i.e an inner class.

```
public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration typeDeclarationStatement) {

    if (!typeDeclarationStatement.isPackageMemberTypeDeclaration()) {
            System.out.println(typeDeclarationStatement.getName());
            // Get more details from the type declaration.
    }

    return true;
}
```

For getting anonymous inner classes use the below code too:

```
public boolean visit(AnonymousClassDeclaration anonyomousClassDeclaration) {

    System.out.println(anonyomousClassDeclaration.toString());

    return true;
}
```

Details on Class traversal using JDT can be found from below link:

- [Eclipse create CompilationUnit from .java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166862/eclipse-create-compilationunit-from-java-file/11168301#11168301)

Comment: i used the code below but it does not display all inner classes

Comment: Does the code doesn't display any inner classes, or is it problem with some specific inner class (anonymous/method inner class)?

Comment: ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setSource(fileName.toString().toCharArray());
    parser.setResolveBindings(true); parser.setCompilerOptions(options);
    final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
   cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
  
 
 public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration typeDeclarationStatement) {

    if (!typeDeclarationStatement.isPackageMemberTypeDeclaration()) {
            System.out.println(typeDeclarationStatement.getName());
    }

    return true;
}

Answer (score 1):

If you have an IType instance (type) then you can query the inner classes by

```
type.getTypes();
```

which will give you an array of the immediate member types declared by this type.

Comment: But you have a ICompilationUnit instance? If so, you can get all top-level type declarations of this compilation unit with ICompilationUnit.getTypes()