# Eclipse create CompilationUnit handle from String

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, compilationunit

My question is similar to [Eclipse create CompilationUnit from .java file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166862/eclipse-create-compilationunit-from-java-file) however I don't have a file and I would like to create a handle for a CompilationUnit with given contents without actually creating underlying resources.

The actual goal is to get an object of type `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType`, so using `setSource(char[] source)` doesn't solve the problem since there are no bindings in the resulting AST.

Do I necessary have to create a temporary file to fulfill my requirement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse create CompilationUnit from .java file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166862/eclipse-create-compilationunit-from-java-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
public void setSource(char[] source)
```

version of the `ASTParser.setSource` method to give it the source of the code you want to process in a character array rather than a file.

Comment: This is unfortunately insufficient because my goal is get an object of type `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType` and I cannot use `resolveBinding()` on resulting `ASTNode` if I use `setSource` without JDT